# Groovy/Grails null safe operator usage in the last part of an expression allowed?

Tags: groovy

I want to know if I can use the Groovy null safe operator in the last part of an expression. I have seen this:

`a?.b?.c` but I can't seem to use `a?.b?.c?`

I need to use this in an if statement check so instead of doing:

`if (a.b.c != null && (a.b.c == something))` can I shorthand it like this:

```
if (a.b.c? == something)
```

Thanks

Comment: The operator is `?.`, not `?`, so a single ? at the end of an expression doesn't make sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the null-check checks the variable BEFORE `?` in order to make sure the property AFTER it can be called. If one of these conditions is not met, it makes no sense to use the operator

UPDATE

you can call the `equals`

```
if( a.b.c?.equals( something ) )
```

Answer (score 1):

You need

```
if (a?.b?.c == something)
```

The `?` at the end wouldn't add anything (even if it did work) as the short circuit operator just make sure the next thing in the expression can handle null cleanly

Comment: Unless of course something is null ... in which case that doesn't mimic the question's intent.

Comment: True, but I have no idea why the question is checking null before the equality

Comment: I suspect it's for that exact reason. `a.b.c` should match `something` unless it's `null` and avoid the case of matching `something` when `something` is also `null`. Sounds messy to me (: